# How to write a lambda expression when you are using a string array?

Tags: java, arrays, regex, lambda, java-8

I want to use a lambda expression instead of a classic for.

```
 String str = "Hello, Maria has 30 USD.";
 String[] FORMAT = {"USD", "CAD"};
 final String simbol = "$";

 //  This was the initial implementation. 
 //  for (String s: FORMAT) {
 //      str = str.replaceAll(s + "\\s",  "\\" + FORMAT);
 //  } 

 Arrays.stream(FORMAT).forEach(country -> {
      str = str.replaceAll(country + "\\s",  "\\" + simbol);
 });  

 // and I tried to do like that, but I receiced an error 
 // "Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final"
 // but I don't want the str String to be final
```

For any string, I want to change the USD or CAD in $ simbol.
How can I changed this code to work ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use [`Matcher.quoteReplacement(simbol)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)) instead of `"\\" + simbol`.

Comment: But, as Andronicus notes in the answer below, your original loop was the correct approach.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: You're wanting to use *streams*, not lambda expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no problem with using a loop for this. That's how I'd likely do it.

You can do it with a stream using `reduce`:

```
str = Arrays.stream(FORMAT)
    .reduce(
        str,
        (s, country) -> s.replaceAll(country + "\\s", Matcher.quoteReplacement(simbol)));
```

Or, easier:

```
str = str.replaceAll(
    Arrays.stream(FORMAT).collect(joining("|", "(", ")")) + "\\s",
    Matcher.quoteReplacement(simbol));
```

Comment: Aside from main question `country + "\\s` should probably be `country + "\\b` (word boundary), otherwise `USD.` will not be replaced as there is no space after `USD`.

Comment: @Pshemo sure; but we should also maybe point out that you don't write "30$", but rather "$30". It's not exactly a good approach overall.

Comment: "*you don't write "30$", but rather "$30"*" oh, today I learned, thanks.

Comment: I had a similar idea as your second aproach with `Pattern.compile(String.join("|", FORMAT)).matcher(str).replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement(symbol));` But this and also yours will replace something like USDBLAH to $BLAH

Comment: The `reduce` variant is violating the associativity constraint. The regex variant is mandating the trailing space only for the last format. You need either `"("+String.join("|", FORMAT)+")\\s"` or `String.join("\\s|", FORMAT)+"\\s"` to mandate that every variant needs a space behind it.

Comment: You don’t need another string concatenation after `collect`, just use `joining("|", "(", ")\\s")`

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a traditional for loop, since you're changing a global variable:

```
for(String country: FORMAT) {
    str = str.replaceAll(country + "\\s",  "\\" + simbol);
}
```

Using `Stream`s in this example will make things less readable.

Comment: Isn't that what OP started with?

Comment: @Pshemo right, I misread the question and ended up with this answer, since I reached the limit I cannot delete it and have to come up with some other solution;>